# mx:DateField and binding inside a Form

Tags: apache-flex, datefield, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a Form with several FormItems and one of those include an mx:DateField. I am not sure how I should bind the DateField values. I have tried the following which none work:

```
<mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true" text="@{dateValue}"/>
<mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true" selectedDate="{dateValue}"/>
```

Now eventually I am trying to store/retrieve the date as a string in the db.
Any help or best practice would be appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: Show us your variable definition for the dateValue property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true" text="{dateValue as string}"/>
```

Try it without the @.

Also, this assumes that the date in the bound variable is in the "mm/dd/yyyy" format.  If it's not then that could be the problem.

Comment: without the @ indeed I can get the value and display it. Also can choose a different one. But how will I bind it in order to send it to my service? Using the @ gives me the following compile error Multiple markers at this line:
-dateValue
-1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value.

Answer (score 0):

in your markup, try this (generally I put it right before my application's closing tag):

```
<mx:Binding source="dateValue" destination = "WhereEverItsGoing" twoway="true"/>
```

that should set up a two way binding between the datefield and the object you send to the service.

Maybe.

Comment: This is not necessarily needed in Flex 4.  The @ syntax is shorthand for two way binding.